# Java API documentation

Tags: java, api, jar, intellisense, javadoc

How can I add Java documentation to a .JAR file so that when people are using my JAR file and type '.' Eclipse will display the documentation for the available API's (intellisense).

**MORE INFO**

I have java doc created but when I export the jar file it does not contain intellisense when used in other projects.  This is what I am having trouble with.

**UPDATE**
The intellisense only shows up if the export the source.  However I want to hide the source code.  How can I get around this?

Comment: [Writing JavaDocs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html)

Comment: Adding Java doc might help. It used to work with Netbeans, not sure if it will in Eclipse though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to include the entire source code with your .jar, you can zip/jar up just the javadocs (however you generate them.. I do it using the Project->Generate Javadoc menu option in Eclipse).  An end user can then "attach" them to the referenced library in the project build path settings.

The javadoc location attribute of a project library can be a URL, a local directory or a local archive file.

After noticing your edits, I might want to mention that Ant has a [javadoc task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javadoc.html) that can generate your javadocs during a build.

Answer (score 3):

Maven has a very elegant way of handling this.

Step 1: The Maven way to ***generate*** javadocs: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/

Step 2: To ensure Eclipse always ***attaches*** these docs, use the [maven-eclipse-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html#downloadJavadocs)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Once these two steps are done, the consumers of your API jars will always have your latest javadocs with no further intervention

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, export the project with sources.

Do File -> Export... -> Java -> JAR File -> Next

Then select the checkbox Export java source files and resources.

Then go on until the JAR is created.

**Edit**: after the edits in the question, this answer is no longer valid, but it is still useful.